# Joining inputs for a complicated output

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Im new in azure analytics. Im using analytics to get feedbacks from users. There are about 50 events that im sending to azure in a second and im trying to get a combined result from two inputs but couldnt get a working output. My problem is in sql query for output.

Now I'm sending in the inputs.

Recommandations:

`{"appId":"1","sequentialId":"28","ItemId":"1589018","similaristyValue":"0.104257207028537","orderId":"0"}`

ShownLog:

`{"appId":"1","sequentialId":"28","ItemId":"1589018"}`

I need to join them with sequentialId and ItemId and calculate the difference between two ordered sequential.

For example: I send 10 Recommandations events and after that (like after 2 sec) i send 3 ShownLog event. So what i need to do is i have to get sum of first 3 (because i send 3 shownlog event) event's similaristyValue ordered by "orderid" from "Recommandations". I also need to get the sum of similarityValues from "ShownLog". At the end i need an input like (for every sequential ID):

sequentialID   Difference
168            1.21

What i ve done so far is. I save all the inputs my azure sql and i ve managed to write the sql i want. You may find the mssql query for it:

```
declare @sumofSimValue float;
declare @totalItemCount int;
declare @seqId float;

select 
    @sumofSimValue = sum(b.[similarityValue]),
    @totalItemCount = count(*),
    @seqId = a.sequentialId 
        from EventHubShownLog a inner join EventHubResult b on a.sequentialId=b.sequentialId and a.ItemId=b.ItemId group by a.sequentialId

        --select @sumofSimValue,@totalItemCount,@seqId


  SELECT @seqId, SUM([similarityValue])-@sumofSimValue
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@totalItemCount) [similarityValue]
    FROM [EventHubResult] where sequentialId=@seqId order by orderId
) AS T
```

But it gives lots of error in analytics. Also it lacks the logic of azure analytcs. I hope i could tell the problem.

Can you tell me how can i do such a job for my system? How can i use the time windows or how can i join them properly?

Answer (score 0):

For every shown log, you have to select sum of similarity value. Is that the intention? Why not just join and select sum? It would only select as many rows as there are shown logs.

One thing to decide is the maximum time difference between recommendation events and shown log events, with that you can use Azure Stream analytics join, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835026.aspx